# The method '[]' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null' - unable to take the value I need

Tags: flutter, dart

```
void main() {
  var value = [
    {
      "abx": [
        {
          "avv": "blah",
          "asd": [
            {
              "topic":
                  "Random.",
              "alternate": "Random2"
            }
          ]
        },        
        {
          "avv1": "bluh",
          "asc": [
            {
              "topic":
                  "Ran4.",
              "alternate": "Ran5"
            }
          ]
        },        
      ]
    }
  ];
  var word = value[0]['abx'][0]['asd'][0]['topic'];
  print(word);
}
```

I want to be able to access the value of "topic" (which is "Random") but I don't know how to do so. Although the error message tells me to use ? or ! operators, it still does not seem to work. Can someone tell me what the problem is

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```dart
void main() {
  var value = [
    {
      "abx": [
        {
          "avv": "blah",
          "asd": [
            {
              "topic":
                  "Random.",
              "alternate": "Random2"
            }
          ]
        },        
        {
          "avv1": "bluh",
          "asc": [
            {
              "topic":
                  "Ran4.",
              "alternate": "Ran5"
            }
          ]
        },        
      ]
    }
  ];
  var word = ((value[0]['abx'] as List<dynamic>)[0]['asd'] as List<dynamic>)[0]['topic'];
  print(word);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This error is because of `null-safety` in **Dart**. Because you are fetching the `values` from and `List` which contains multiple data and any them can be `null` so it will just want us to ensure that `receiver` will have some value.

You can solve this error by adding `!` or `?` in your code right after the `receiver` like below :

```
 var word = value[0]['abx']![0]['asd']![0]['topic'];
```

Or

```
 var word = value[0]['abx']?[0]['asd']?[0]['topic'];
```

Also change the declaration of your variable like :

```
 final List<Map<String, dynamic>> value = [];
```

Or

```
final value = [] as List<Map<String, dynamic>>;
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Although the error for the 2nd [0] goes off, there is an error for the 3rd [0]

Comment: You need to change your declaration type as well to solve this. See update.

Comment: Because you can't cast for every variable if you have a lot manually like you are trying to cast after cast. Rest is your choice.